# How do you pass values of select input using simple form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, simple-form

Form is submitting the values as nil, although I selected a value.

```
<%= simple_form_for @offer do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :days_per_turn, "Days Per Turn" %>
<%= f.select :days_per_turn, [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 14 ], selected: '1' %>
<%= f.label :play_as, "I Play As" %>
<%= f.select :play_as, [ 'Random', 'White', 'Black' ], selected: 'Random' %>
<%= f.label :rated, "Rated" %>
<%= f.select :rated, [ 'Yes', 'No', 'Takeback' ], selected: 'No' %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a piece of advice: Keep in mind that Rails and its ecosystem is built with web app development in mind. More often than not, a problem is already solved — such as an initialized form's values. The more you try to reinvent the wheel, the more issues you'll face. Stick to its conventions and you'll have a good time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll do better to use the [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) [syntax](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections):

```
<%= simple_form_for @offer do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :days_per_turn, "Days Per Turn" %>
      <%= f.input :days_per_turn, collection: [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[5,5],[7,7],[10,10],[14,14]], selected: 1 %>

      <%= f.label :play_as, "I Play As" %>
      <%= f.input :play_as, collection: [['Random', :random], ['White', :white], ['Black', :black]], selected: :random %>

      <%= f.label :rated, "Rated" %>
      <%= f.input :rated, collection: [['Yes', :yes],['No', :no], ['Takeback', :takeback]], selected: :no %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If the above doesn't work, you need to provide the params which is being sent to your controller after submit.

Comment: It is working now. It was the params that I had a typo. Thanks, Rick. Both yours and mine works.